# Javascript parses integer as NaN?

Tags: javascript, integer, d3.js

I'm parsing some data to display in a graph, yet I consistently get NaN when I parse my integers. I know that generally means that they're not parsed correctly, but I'm using `parseint` and I thought that would fix things. I'm parsing the Unixtime (first field) and then three other fields (correctly parsed). Yet, whenever I go to display the Unixtime it fails. I've declared scale.linear for x, though time.scale also fails.

The code snippet I'm using is below:

```
d3.tsv("<?php echo $field; ?>values.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Unixtime"; }));
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Unixtime = parseInt(d.Unixtime/1000);
  });
  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {Unixtime: d.Unixtime, value: parseFloat(d[name]/1000)};
      })
    };
  });
```

The error message I'm getting is below from the Chrome debugger.

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,1.7527908403982337CNaN,1.7527908403982337,NaN,1.7527908403982337,NaN,1.751122428294669CNaN
```

The data looks like:

```
1353168433      5557    6404    5510

1353175632      5478    6404    5510

1353182750      5432    6404    5510
```

Comment: So, what does `console.log(d.Unixtime)` produce right before you `parseInt()` it?

Comment: And why are you bothering to `parseFloat` something *after* dividing it by 1000?

Comment: Maybe instead of `parseInt(d.Unixtime/1000)`, you need `parseInt(d.Unixtime)/1000`. Divide after parsing the int.

Comment: What is the value of name? Are you sure it is an integer and not a String?

Comment: @jdwire shouldn't matter: http://jsfiddle.net/K67vG/ his `d.Unixtime` must not be parse-able.

Comment: Side note: always pass a second `radix` parameter (usually `10`) to `parseInt`/`parseFloat` to handle cases where your string begins with `0`, `0x`, etc

Comment: Is the problem with: parseFloat(d[name]/1000), is d[name] a string? if so you need to parse that before dividing otherwise you are trying to divide a string by 1000.

Comment: HJO5, that's not the issue. The /1000 was actually a scaling issue. Minitech, that was dead code. Thanks for pointing that out. jdwire, I did that. Thanks for pointing it out. SteveS, positive. My y-axis is just fine.

Comment: Alvaro: Interesting! It prints undefined. Sorry, that's a rookie mistake. I'm new to JS. So, I looked. it turns out that the data I'm parsing wasn't actually a Unixtime name! It was just "time." Interesting. Regardless, all of these suggestions actually helped. Thank you, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
d.Unixtime = parseInt(d.Unixtime/1000);
```

When you divide it by 1000, you get a decimal number. Try `parseFloat()` instead:

```
d.Unixtime = parseFloat(d.Unixtime/1000);
```

Alternatively you could `/1000` after converting to int:

```
d.Unixtime = parseInt(d.Unixtime)/1000;
```

Comment: While I agree that I should have been doing that outside, moving it to the outside, parsing it as any of those does not fix the problem. Thanks for pointing out that poor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that console.log(d.Unixtime) as per Alvaro's suggestion printed undefined. With that, I went back in and noticed that the name of the field was somehow changed to time, rather than unixtime. After changing it, it works. Thanks everyone!

```
d3.tsv("<?php echo $field; ?>values.tsv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "time"; }));
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Unixtime = parseInt(d.time,10)/1000;
  });
  var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {time: d.time, value: parseFloat(d[name],10)/1000};
      })
    };
  });
```